# Capturing windows event with java windows services

Tags: java, windows-services, event-log

I want to capture lock/unlock/start/shutdown/log off and log on events through a windows service and then I want to fire a function for each event so that I can capture the time when Event occured.

I want to do this through a windows service so that I need not run the program manually. And I want to run this program through java language.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you will need to use [JNA](http://jna.java.net/) and write the capture code with native Windows calls.

There is a class [java.awt.Robot](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) that does the reverse -- simulating OS events but I am not aware of the way to capture events in pure Java.

Answer (score 0):

In C# it is pretty straightforward. I can show you code in C#, you can then convert it to Ja.Net if you want to use Java as a language. (if you actually want to use JVM, this won't help as much though).

1. Create empty C# service.
2. Inside your program Main method set CanHandleSessionChangeEvent property to true:

   ```
   /// <summary>
   /// The main entry point for the application.
   /// </summary>
   static void Main()
   {
       ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
       LogService logService = new LogService();
       logService.CanHandleSessionChangeEvent = true;
       ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
       { 
           logService 
       };
       ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
   }
   ```
3. in service implementation override OnSessionChange event, where you can dump information on user logon/logoff and session connect/disconnect

   ```
   protected override void OnSessionChange(SessionChangeDescription changeDescription)
   {
       EventLog.WriteEvent(
           new EventInstance(100, 0, EventLogEntryType.Information), 
           String.Format("Reason: {0}, SessionId:{1}", changeDescription.Reason, changeDescription.SessionId));
       base.OnSessionChange(changeDescription);
   }
   ```
4. Register service, start it up and see records in event log.